# How could I go about proving this summation of a rising factorial?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}r(r+1)(r+2)...(r+p-1) = \frac{1}{p+1}n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+p)$$

So I get how to do this with limited terms, like r(r+1) just ends up with some summations of r, r^2 and onward, but how could I prove this generalization? I tried doing something with induction, but I got lost on how would the p increment for the n+1 case.

Comment: Do you need only induction ? There are other methods also for this..

Comment: oh if you have another solution other than induction that would be great, I would love to see it! I'm just learning induction currently.

Comment: It's one of the beauties of induction on sums.  To prove $\sum f(r) = h(n)$. it is just a matter of proving i)$f(1)=h(1)$ and ii) $h(n) + f(n+1) = h(n+1)$.  That strategy works nearly all the time.

Comment: @fleablood I agree. simple yet elegant.

Comment: yup, I love new perspectives on the problem. Good proof! I'll include it in my paper - citing you of course :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Induction step:
Suppose true for $n$. Then 
$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{r=1}^{n+1}r(r+1)\ldots(r+p-1)&=\sum_{r=1}^nr(r+1)\ldots(r+p-1)+(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(n+p)\\
&=\frac{1}{p+1}n(n+1)\ldots(n+p)+(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(n+p)\\&=\frac{1}{p+1}\left(n(n+1)\ldots(n+p)+(p+1)(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(n+p)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{p+1}\left((n+1)\ldots(n+p)\right)(n+(p+1))\\
&=\frac{1}{p+1}(n+1)\ldots(n+p)(n+1+p)
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I'm confused a bit, is the last line equal to our original case? or is there something I'm not seeing

Comment: @mathkid225 The last line shows that the statement holds with $n+1$ instead of $n$, which proves the induction step.

Comment: i.e. we have shown when the statement holds for $n$, it must also hold for $n+1$

Comment: OH I SEE, thank you thank you! so if you plug in n+1 straight you would get that last line from our original formula

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 4):

We claim that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}\tag{1}.
$$
Indeed the RHS counts the number of $k+1$ element subsets of $\{0,1\dotsc,n\}$. The LHS counts the same thing by classifying the subsets based on their maximum element. For $0\leq i\leq n$, there are $\binom{i}{k}$ subsets of $\{0,1\dotsc,n\}$ whose maximum element is $i$.

Now observe that
$$
\sum_{r=1}^{n}r(r+1)(r+2)...(r+p-1)=p!\sum_{r=1}^n\binom{r+p-1}{p}=p!\sum_{u=p}^{n+p-1}\binom{u}{p}=p!\binom{n+p}{p+1}
$$
where in the last equality we used (1). But
$$
p!\binom{n+p}{p+1}=p!\times\frac{n(n+1)\dotsb(n+p)}{(p+1)!}=\frac{n(n+1)\dotsb(n+p)}{p+1}
$$
as desired.

Comment: Beautiful, could you explain how you linked your first equation to the problem? Like what made you think of doing this way? Does it have something to do with combinatorics.

Comment: @mathkid225: The first step is writing the product as binomial coefficient. Then by experience we recognize the *[hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity)*.

Answer (score 3):

For $n=1$ it is true. Suppose it is true for $n$. Then 
\begin{align}
\sum_{r\le n+1}r(r+1)\cdots (r+p-1)&=\frac{n(n+1)\cdots (n+p)}{p+1}+(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+p) \\
&=\frac{(n+1)\cdots (n+p+1)}{p+1},\\
\end{align}
which completes the induction.

Comment: how did you get that +(n+1(n+2)..(n+p) term on the right?

also how did you get (n + p + 1) on the 2nd line

Comment: That's just r(r+1).... (r+p-1) when r = (n+1).

Comment: yup I got it now!

Answer (score 3):

Since you were also open to other methods than induction, we can try telescoping method of sums.

Our original sum is something like

$$S = \sum_{r=1}^{n} \prod_{k=0}^{p-1} (r+k)$$

Let us define new terms in the following manner:

$$\begin{align}
T_r &= \prod_{k=0}^{p}(r+k) \\
T_{r+1}-T_r &= \prod_{k=0}^{p}(r+1+k)-\prod_{k=0}^{p}(r+k) \\
T_{r+1}-T_r &= (p+1)\prod_{k=0}^{p-1}(r+1+k)
\end{align}$$

Now sum from $r=-1$ to $n-1$ and on left side we get terms cancelling. On right side we get our required sum. Also note that $T_{-1} = 0$:

$$T_n - T_{-1} = (p+1)S \\
 \implies S = \frac{T_n}{p+1}=\frac{\prod_{k=0}^{p}(n+k)}{p+1}$$

Comment: could you explain how to the terms cancel when r=-1 to n-1

and how do you go through these steps? Not super familiar with product summations

$$\begin{align}
T_r &= \prod_{k=0}^{p}(r+k) \\
T_{r+1}-T_r &= \prod_{k=0}^{p}(r+1+k)-\prod_{k=0}^{p}(r+k) \\
T_{r+1}-T_r &= (p+1)\prod_{k=0}^{p-1}(r+1+k)
\end{align}$$

Comment: @mathkid225 for that take factors starting from $(r+1)$ till $(r+p)$ common from both terms. And for cancellation, $ r= -1, n-1$ terms dont cancel. Rest all cancel out. Start by writing some terms like: $T_2 - T_1 + (T_1 - T_0) + (T_0 - T_{-1})$ etc..

Comment: ok I'm starting to see it, thank you for the proof!

Answer (score 2):

A good candidate for induction I think.

If you can show $\frac 1{p+1} n(n+1)....(n+p) + (n+1)(n+2)....(n+p) = \frac 1{p+1}(n+1)(n+2)....(n+p+1)$ you are done[$*$].

And that's just a matter of factoring.

And $\frac 1{p+1} n(n+1)....(n+p) + (n+1)(n+2)....(n+p)= (\frac 1{p+1}*n + 1)[(n+1)...(n+p)]=$

$(\frac {n+(p+1)}{p+1})[(n+1)...(n+p)]$

$\frac 1{p+1}[(n+1)...(n+p)](n+p+1)$

$\frac 1{p+1}(n+1).....(n+p+1)$

====

[$*$] Formally:  Let $f(r) = r(r_1)....(r+ p + 1)$.

Let $h(n) = \frac 1{p+1}n(n+1)....(n+p)$

We need to prove $\sum\limits_{r=1}^n f(r) = h(n)$.

Step 1: Prove $\sum\limits_{r=1}^1 f(r) =f(1) = h(1)$

in other words $1*2*3....p  = \frac 1{p+1}1*2*.....*p*(p+1)$.

That's very easy.

Step 2: Prove $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n+1} f(r)= \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}f(r) + f(n+1)=$

$h(n) + f(n+1) = h(n+1)$.

.... which is ...

$\frac 1{p+1} n(n+1)....(n+p) + (n+1)(n+2)....(n+p) = \frac 1{p+1}(n+1)(n+2)....(n+p+1)$

Which is done above.  It's just a matter of factoring.

Comment: wow, looks complicated. is this just induction with more rigor? Thank you, by the way, this is really helpful!

how did you get from here to here $\frac 1{p+1} n(n+1)....(n+p) + (n+1)(n+2)....(n+p)= (\frac 1{p+1}*n + 1)[(n+1)...(n+p)]=$

$(\frac {n+(p+1)}{p+1})[(n+1)...(n+p)]$

Comment: That's factoring $\frac 1{p+1} n(n+1)....(n+p)$ and $(n+1)(n+2)....(n+p)$ have $K=(n+1)(n+2)....(n+p)$ in common.  So I factor it out... leaving $\frac 1{p+1}nK + K = (\frac 1{p+1}*n + 1)K$.  That's all.

Comment: It's induction with *less* rigor.  If $\sum_{k=0}^n f(k) = h(n)$ then $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} =\sum_{k=0}^n f(k) + f(n+1) = h(n) + f(n+1)$.  So prove $h(n) + f(n+1) = h(n+1)$ and you will be done.  This should be your *first* thought with all induction over sums.

Comment: oh ok, thank you so much!

Comment: Example $\sum_{i=0}^n i= \frac {n(n+1)}2$.  Proof: i) $n=1\implies 1 = \frac {1(1+1)}2$.  ii) if $\sum_{i=0}^n i = \frac {n(n+1)}2$ then $\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} i = (n+1) +\sum_{i=0}^n i = (n+1) + \frac {n(n+1)}2 = \frac {2(n+1)}2 + \frac {n(n+1)}2 = \frac {(n+1)(n+2)}2$.  Thus induction is done.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the result can be stated quite neatly using notation for [rising factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) as follows:

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^{\overline{p}}=\frac {\;\;\;n^{\overline{p+1}}}{p+1}$$

which is analogous to the standard integral

$$\int_0^n r^p\;\text dr=\frac {\;\;n^{\ p+1}}{p+1}$$

The summation can be proven using the [Hockey-Stick Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity),  written in this case as 
$$p!\sum_{r=1}^n\binom {r+p-1}p=p!\binom {n+p}{p+1}$$

Comment: Yup, ended up doing induction and then using the Hockey-Stick identity